# Send automatical email after save to database

Tags: laravel, email, email-confirmation

I am new here.

I have a project in Laravel. I have one textarea and data from it is save in datavase. It works good. Now I would like to send automatical email to one specific email address with this data. It must be sent only one time with save to database.

I have no problem with sending email to customer with data but now I need to send email with data from this textarea to one specific email. It is a textarea what we have to buy for customer. It must be sent to our cooperation company.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can use eloquent events to send email when a new record is created on specific model. see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse this is possible!

You should take a look at the following resources :

#### Observers

https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/eloquent#observers

#### Notifications

https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/notifications
-> specifically : https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/notifications#mail-notifications

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I have this route for email:
` Route::get('/print/{id}', 'PrintController@printOrder')->name('print');
 Route::get('/print-archive/{id}', 'PrintController@printArchive')->name('print.archive');
 Route::get('/email/create/{id}', 'EmailController@create')->name('email.create');
 Route::post('/email/send/{id}   ', 'EmailController@sendOrderMail')->name('email.send');
 Route::get('/email/{id}', 'EmailController@send')->name('email');
 Route::get('/email-check', 'EmailController@checkEmails')->name('email-check');`

Comment: Could I add route in public funktion?

Comment: You could add a route somewhere to trigger the mailing if that is what u mean? I think you should take a look at the docs provided in my answer, and take a look at Laracasts to find some tutorials on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can just trigger your function after saving: for example, after saving in controller.

```
public function store(Request $request){

        $var = new Property; //your model 
        $var->title=$request->title; // the input that being save to database.
        $var ->save();
        // Send email to that input
       Mail::send('email',['email'=>$request->title],function ($mail) use($request){
            $mail->from('info@sth.com');
            $mail->to($request->title);
        });        

       return redirect()->back()->with('message','Email Successfully Sent!');
    }
```